# td element not parsed to int

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with id #tab1.
For each row, I want to calculate the value of column Points / Matches and to put it in the column Coeficiency, but my code doesn't work. 
The numbers aren't parsed to int. I would always like to know if 
   elem[4].innerHTML(z);  is ok to set coeficiency.

```js
Average();

function Average() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tab1'),
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr');

  //console.log(rows.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    elem = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("columns");
    var x = parseInt(elem[2]);
    var y = parseInt(elem[3]);
    // console.log(x+y," ");
    console.log(x, " ", y);
    var z = y / x;
    elem[4].innerHTML(z);
  }
```

```html
<div id="mytable">
  <table id="tab1">
    <tr class="rows">
      <th class="columns">#</th>
      <th class="columns">Team</th>
      <th class="columns">Matches</th>
      <th class="columns">Points</th>
      <th class="columns">Coeficiency</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">1</td>
        <td class="columns">Baetasii</td>
        <td class="columns">3</td>
        <td class="columns">9</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">Carcotasii</td>
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">5</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, have you checked out [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)? The `parseInt` function accepts a string, not an element, try somethign like `x=parseInt(elem[2].textContent)`.

Comment: You have a bunch of small errors in your HTML, and a missing closing `}` at the end of your script. I recommend using an editor with code highlighting. `th` rows should be inside `thead`, just like you have with `tbody`. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eks23uwz/

Comment: You need to exchange to following lines of code `<tbody>` and `</tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so a few pointers having looked over your code, first of all `innerHTML` is not a function, it's a simple property, you can just reassign it, however, I suggest using [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) due to the fact that using `innerHTML`, you can allow for XSS to occur.

I mean I know XSS probably isn't an issue in this specific scenario, however I thought it my be of value mentioning that.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments above, using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), you need to pass it a string rather than an object which is what you were originally doing. Using functions such as `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`, you'll have an array-like object, such as a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which contains a number of objects, usually [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) or [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).

```js
Average();

function Average() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tab1'),
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr');

  //console.log(rows.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    elem = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("columns");
    var x = parseInt(elem[2].textContent);
    var y = parseInt(elem[3].textContent);
    // console.log(x+y," ");
    console.log(x, " ", y);
    var z = y / x;
    elem[4].textContent = z;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mytable">
  <table id="tab1">
    <tr class="rows">
      <th class="columns">#</th>
      <th class="columns">Team</th>
      <th class="columns">Matches</th>
      <th class="columns">Points</th>
      <th class="columns">Coeficiency</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">1</td>
        <td class="columns">Baetasii</td>
        <td class="columns">3</td>
        <td class="columns">9</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">Carcotasii</td>
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">5</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

## Edit

I thought I'd also include a neater version, it does near enough the same logic stuff, it's more or less just more modern JavaScript syntax, using a more 'functional-style'. Originally I *basically* copied the exact same style that you provided for the sake of simplicity, but I thought that there's a few issues with that. An example being how you've used a capital letter for the `Average`, personally I only use a capital letter at the start of a name if it's a class, this is a personal choice however, feel free to disagree or stick to what you know!

I personally prefer using more modern syntax as **personally** I think is easier to read, it's more clear and concise, generally it looks like less code to read through.

```js
// States if an array like object is empty or not. 
const isEmpty = a => a.length > 0;

// Returns the text content of a html object.
const txt = td => td == null ? null : td.textContent;

// Simply updates the UI.
const render = tds => v => tds[4].textContent = parseFloat(v).toFixed(2);

// Works out whether or not to fire update or do nothing.
const compute = tds => isEmpty(tds) ? render(tds)(txt(tds[3]) / txt(tds[2])) : null;

// Gets the average for each tr. 
const avg = trs => trs.forEach(tr => compute(tr.querySelectorAll("td")));

// Fire the avg function. 
const update = () => avg(document.querySelectorAll("#tab1 tbody tr"));

// Render tr tag.
const renderTr = i => n => m => p => `<tr>
  <td>${i}</td><td>${n}</td><td>${m}</td><td>${p}</td><td></td>
</tr>`;

// Add a table row.
const append = () => {
  const tbl = document.getElementById("tab1");
  const i = document.querySelectorAll("#tab1 tbody tr").length,
    n = '_____',
    m = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    p = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

  // Safe-ish because what's being entered is controlled 100%.
  // But generally try not to use innerHTML.
  tbl.innerHTML += renderTr(i)(n)(m)(p);
  update();
};

// Allow for auto add. 
document.getElementById("add").onclick = append;
update(); // Initial run.
```

```html
<div id="mytable">
  <table id="tab1">
    <tr class="rows">
      <th class="columns">#</th>
      <th class="columns">Team</th>
      <th class="columns">Matches</th>
      <th class="columns">Points</th>
      <th class="columns">Coeficiency</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">1</td>
        <td class="columns">Baetasii</td>
        <td class="columns">3</td>
        <td class="columns">9</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rows">
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">Carcotasii</td>
        <td class="columns">2</td>
        <td class="columns">5</td>
        <td class="columns">100%</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<button id="add">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object#values Array#forEach #getElementsByTagName

The main issue is that you needed to retrieve the text value with `innerText`.

You also don't need the redundant class names.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const rows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr");

Object.values(rows).forEach(row => {
  const tds = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (tds.length === 5) {
    const x = parseInt(tds[2].innerText),
      y = parseInt(tds[3].innerText);
    const z = y / x;
    tds[4].innerText = `${z}`;
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Matches</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>Coeficiency</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Baetasii</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Carcotasii</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Since we have a collection of *DOM* elements, `elem[2]` it's a `DOM` element and you should access its `textContent` property.

Also, you're using `innerHTML` property in a wrong way. Just replace

```
 elem[4].innerHTML(z);
```

to

```
 elem[4].innerHTML = z;
```

```js
Average();

function Average() {
  var table = document.getElementById('tab1'),
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    elem = rows[i].getElementsByClassName("columns");
    var x = parseInt(elem[2].textContent);
    var y = parseInt(elem[3].textContent);
    console.log(x, " ", y);
    var z = y / x;
    elem[4].innerHTML = z;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mytable">
  <table id="tab1">
    <tr class="rows">
      <th class="columns">#</th>
      <th class="columns">Team</th>
      <th class="columns">Matches</ht>
        <th class="columns">Points</th>
        <th class="columns">Coeficiency</th>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="rows">
            <td class="columns">1</td>
            <td class="columns">Baetasii</td>
            <td class="columns">3</td>
            <td class="columns">9</td>
            <td class="columns">100%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="rows">
            <td class="columns">2</td>
            <td class="columns">Carcotasii</td>
            <td class="columns">2</td>
            <td class="columns">5</td>
            <td class="columns">100%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: *as a NodeList object* - in most cases `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection` object (which differs from a `NodeList` object).

Comment: Also, `tbody` cannot be a child of `tr`. The HTML is invalid, and even if that is from OP's code, it should be corrected in any answer given.